# Displaying Png image using Barby Barcode generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, png, barcode

I am using barby and its the png outputter. I have gotten it to compile fine, but I am not sure how I can display the image. Here is the code..

Controller:

```
@barcode = Barby::Code128B.new(@num)
@blob = Barby::PngOutputter.new(@barcode).to_png #Raw PNG data
File.open('barcode.png', 'w'){|f| f.write @blob }
```

Application Helper:

```
require 'barby'
require 'barby/barcode/code_128'
require 'barby/outputter/png_outputter'
```

View:

```
<%= @blob %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `@blob` is image data, you can't just "print" it like a regular string. You need to use [image_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_tag%5d) instead, and give it the path to your image. Something like:

```
<%= image_tag("barcode.png") %>
```

Comment: I am getting this "invalid byte sequence in UTF-8"

Comment: hum `Barby` is probably not returning the path. If you try `<%= image_tag("barcode.png") %>` ?

Comment: That runs fine, but I can't see the image. Its just an empty square.

Comment: and you are sure that the file `barcode.png` was well generated (if you open it yourself)?

Comment: Yep. I got it! the problem was that I was missing the "/" in front of the image. So it worked with "/barcode.png"

Answer (score 4):

You can generate a png file first and then show that file with an image_tag like @mdemolin proposed.

If you have a dynamically generated image an alternative is to generate the image everytime and send the correct headers with the data.

Controller

```
@barcode = Barby::Code128B.new(@num)
@blob = Barby::PngOutputter.new(@barcode).to_png

respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.png do
    send_data @blob, type: "image/png", disposition: "inline"
  end
end
```

And then you add an image_tag in a view with:

```
image_tag(url_for({:controller => 'barby', :action => 'show', :format => 'png' }) )
```

Comment: Nice solution thanks.  In your example you can just pass a format:  image_tag(url_for({:controller => 'barby', :action => 'show', :format => "png" }) )

Answer (score 1):

You can also do

```
- code = Barby::Code128B.new(string).to_png(margin:3, height: 10)
- image = Base64.encode64(code.to_s).gsub(/\s+/, "")
= image_tag "data:image/png;base64,#{Rack::Utils.escape(image)}"
```